# How to represent plural rules for Russian or other complex plural languages in ICU MessageFormat

Tags: localization, internationalization, messageformat

How can we represent Russian in ICU MessageFormat given the unusual nature of the pluralization rules?

MessageFormat supports pluralization like `{arg, plural, =1 {one} other {other}}` and more complex `{arg, plural, =0 {none} =1 {one} =2 {few} other {several}}`.

However, sometimes the text to use cannot be directly determined by the number without some calculations; how do we do that? Russian has three plural rules based on the last digit in the number with exceptions for 11-14.

Info I've reviewed:

**Russian language pluralization**

http://www.russianlessons.net/lessons/lesson11_main.php

**MessageFormat Rules**

http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/messages

**Number of plural rules for various languages**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Localization/Localization_and_Plurals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Russian ICU pluralization example for apples (яблоко).

```
{arg, plural, =0 {нет яблок} one {одно яблоко} few {{arg} яблока} other {{arg} яблок}}
```

`one` works for numbers ending with 1, except 11

`few` works for numbers ending with 2, 3, 4, again, except 12, 13 and 14

`other` is just "many" form